# Easier way for multiple if-else tests

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, if-statement

I have a string and I want to execute `if` statement if string value matches  given set of words(say ape,eat,sleep,mango........)

I can do:-

```
if(name=="ape" || name=="eat".............)
```

Is there any easier method to do this?

I want to use if-else ONLY.

Comment: How many words do you have? Do you want the match to be case-sensitive?

Comment: i have 10 words and  yes, I need case sensitive check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decalare an array of the words and then use either the standard algorithm `std::find` or `std::any_of`.

for example

```
const char * words[] =
{
    "ape", "eat", "sleep", "mango"
}; 

if ( std::find( std::begin( words ), std::end( words ), name ) != std::end( words ) )
{
   //...
}
```

if you will declare a sorted array then you can use the standard algorithm `std::binary_search`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const char * words[] =
    {
        "eat", "ape", "mango", "sleep" 
    };

    std::string name( "mango" );

    if ( std::binary_search( std::begin( words ), std::end( words ), name ) )
    {
        std::cout << name << " is a correct name\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
mango is a correct name
```

Or place the words in a  standard container as for example `std::set` and use the find method of the container.

Comment: This would require linear time search. Use `std::unordered_set` instead.

Comment: @MohammadZeineldeen - For a finite and small collection of values any set implementation will have overhead that surpasses the cost of a linear search.

Comment: @MohammadZeineldeen The entire array fits on a cache line and binary searching is logarithmic time.

Comment: His question looks general as he said "given set of words"

Answer (score 2):

There isn't if you want to keep it to only `if` and `else` without anything added.

Otherwise you could use a `std::unordered_set`, fill it with those words and use `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto pattern: {"ape", "eat"}) {
   if(name == pattern) {
      // all the consequences here
      break;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, on a hot path, you could use something like a hash set:

```
static const std::unordered_set<std::string> words{"ape", "eat"};
if(words.find(name) != words.end()) {
}
```

Just make sure it's a `static const`, to not reinitialize it every time anew. It's probably better if you have a real *huge* set of patterns to allow.

Comment: You could also use `if(words.count(name))` to save some typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an unordered_set of string and search for the name.
Something like this:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <unordered_set>
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>

 int main()
 {
     std::unordered_set<std::string> values = { "ape", "stuff", "dude" };


     std::string name = "ape";

     if (std::find(std::begin(values), std::end(values), name) != std::end(values)) {
         std::cout << "found it";
     } else {
         std::cout << "no found it";
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Thanks Sombrero Chicken for mentioning the unordered_set. I defaulted to vector.
There might be some C++17/C++20 version with constexpr unordered_set. But I leave this to someone else.

Comment: There is no `constexpr unordered_set`.  All of the container, minus `std::array`, use allocators which means new which is not allowed in a constexpr context.

Comment: @NathanOliver AFAIK there are proposals to allow constexpr containers. And though not available as of right now, it is possible for the versions of C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance but want minimal code, build a single std::string containing all the words split by a distinct separator character, also at the start and end. Then `std::string::find()` your search word also wrapped in the separator character:

```
static const std::string words("^ape^stuff^dude^");
if (words.find("^"+name+"^") != words.npos)
    std::cout << "found it";
```

Or dispense with the const std::string and use `strstr` from the clib.